# Grid For Texture Editor Doesn't Show Up

Tags: cinema-4d

I was waching a cinema 4d [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwTuJ68N7G0&t=918s) when he selects the texture editor option on the left and a yellow grid pops up. He can then move, scale, rotate the texture that was applied to a object using the yellow grid. I tried the same thing but all that shows up are axis controllers shown below. I tried to use them but they don't do anything. I tried to do the same thing on a simple solid but that didn't work either. PLEASE HELP.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the projection to something other than UVW Mapping... That will allow you to see and manipulate the Texture Grid.